# "Oil change overdue by sticker. (45)"

Tags: oil, oil-change, inspection

I recently brought my car for a 30,000 mile maintenance inspection. It was returned with Repair Order that I didn't read in details at the time.

Now, I realized that there's a note, on the second page, that I don't understand.  It says:

> Note: oil change overdue by sticker. (45)

What does that mean?

Comment: why don't you ask whoever wrote the order?

Comment: @agentp Good point `;-)` The 45 is actually an id for the mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really knowing the full context, I would assume it means there is a sticker in the windshield (usually placed in the upper left corner by service centers here in the States). According to the place you took it too, the mileage on your odometer exceeds the amount of what is registered on the sticker which is indicating it is due for an oil change.

Comment: That is my guess too. Shall I assume that I exceed that mileage by 45 miles?

Comment: 45 could mean the mileage or it could be a generic code for the "problem". Who knows how they would work things.

Comment: if the car was in for 30,000 mile service then it can't have missed a 45,000 change or , maybe the sticker meant 45,000 or 12 months or 6 months and it is exceeded in terms of time - without seeing the details of the sticker....

Comment: my Jeep is 250,000 overdue by sticker :) Never bothered to scrape the sticker off from the last time it was ever professionally serviced.